# How to send logs to Cloudwatch from a background process running in AWS Fargate containers?

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-fargate

I'm using Fargate. My container is running two processes. Celery worker in the background and Django in the foreground. The foreground process emits logs to stdout, hence AWS takes care of sending Django logs to concerned Cloudwatch Log Group and Stream.

Since its running in the background, how do send the celery worker's logs to (a different Log Stream within same Log Group) Cloudwatch?

Answer (score 2):

If there's no way to move the second process to the separate container and log it as usual, you may install awslogs package to the container and set it up to read background process' log files and send content to CloudWatch. 
But I'd not recommend such approach.

Comment: I was aware installing the awslogs agent was an option, but like you said, it's not the way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Again this is not necessarily a `Fargate` based issue or question. For logging in celery check this out http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#logging.

> ```
> The worker won’t update the redirection if you create a logger instance somewhere in your task or task module.
>
> If you want to redirect sys.stdout and sys.stderr to a custom logger you have to enable this manually, for example:
>
> import sys
>
> logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
>
> @app.task(bind=True)
> def add(self, x, y):
>     old_outs = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
>     rlevel = self.app.conf.worker_redirect_stdouts_level
>     try:
>         self.app.log.redirect_stdouts_to_logger(logger, rlevel)
>         print('Adding {0} + {1}'.format(x, y))
>         return x + y
>     finally:
>         sys.stdout, sys.stderr = old_outs
> ```

And for logging with Fargate, i would use the `awslogs` driver. Below is how you configure as documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html

If using the console:

[image]

Or this if in cloudformation template:

[image]

Comment: Since my django app is already logging to stdout, won't the above code mix my django logs and celery logs into same Cloudwatch log stream?

Comment: Container definition is a list, so for every container you can create a different log prefix, in the same log group. But you will have to run them in 2 different containers in a task definition. If both the service are in a single container, the logs will come in a single stream

Comment: Then you have the answer, what else you are expecting ?

Answer (score 0):

Like @OK999 said, Celery is designed to swallow logs whether its on Fargate or not.  We ended up using a Django `LOGGING` config like:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    # This only "disables" but the loggers don't propagate
    # 'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    ...
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': env.str('LOGGING_LEVEL'),
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        ...
        # celery won't route logs to console without this
        'celery': {
            # filtered at the handler
            'level': logging.DEBUG,
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
        ...
```

We had to make this change long before transitioning to Fargate.